# If I installed a Minecraft mod do I still need the backup?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I need to clear up my PC so I need to know if I can delete the minecraft backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup was made in case something goes horribly wrong with the Minecraft installation and you need to revert Minecraft back to what you had originally.

If you feel like you don't need it anymore, then you can delete it